# I did not add a companion on my WizzAir booking with discount

Tags: budget, wizz-air, travel-companions

By mistake I did not add my girlfriend on my booking for WizzAir with discount. Can I add her on the same flight, same date and hour with discount?

Comment: Can you specify more precisely what type of discount you are referring to? Right now, the question is unclear. The only discount mentioned on their site is the one you get when booking flight and hotel together, but it looks like you mean something different.

Comment: I think he's talking about the WIZZ Discount Club.

Answer (score 3):

To use the WIZZ Discount Club, your girlfriend's ticket must be on the same booking as yours. Unfortunately you cannot add passengers to your booking, so you need to create a new one. But I assume that it will cost more so it's not worth it.

From [wizzair.com](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/booking-information/changing-your-reservation#/):

> **Can I add more passengers to my reservation**:
>   Unfortunately this is not possible. You will need to create a new booking.

Comment: Yes i was talking about Wizz Discount Club. Thanks a lot for answer, 
very helpful. <3